# How can we replace , with ',' in T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace

How can we replace , with ',' in T-Sql

i am passing 'a,b,c' as a parameter and i am trying to replace , with ',' so that i can get the output as 'a','b','c'

i have the workaround where we can put it in a temp table and read from that table but i was curious to know if we can achieve it directly using the replace function in Sql server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
select ''''+replace(column1,',',''',''') +''''
from tablename
```

However, there may be more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you were using the parameter

```
DECLARE @Param NVARCHAR(100)
```

You can simply perform the following operation:

```
SET @Param = (SELECT CONCAT('''', REPLACE(@Param ,',',''','''), '''') )
```

I haven't tested this on SQL yet, but I think this should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT Column1 AS CommaSeparatedColumn
    ,'''' + replace(Column1, ',', ''',''') + '''' AS CommaWithinSingleQuotesSeparatedColumn
FROM (
    VALUES ('a,b,c,d')
    ) T(Column1)
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%'
    OR Column1 LIKE '%' + REPLACE(Column1, ',', '%')
```